# Add a button element to each list element

Tags: javascript

I want to add button element to each list element (JavaScript).

This is my code. I used fro loop. In the output, only the last element of the list is getting the button element. What am I doing wrong.

```
function createButtonElement() {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");   `

   btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete Me"));
   var a = document.querySelectorAll("li");

   for(var v =0; v<a.length;v++)
    {
      a[v].appendChild(btn);
    }   
}
```

Comment: is that stray ` on purpose?

Comment: Use array push inside for loop

Comment: You need to create a different button for each `li` element and don't forget to give it a click event listener inside that loop as well as an id or some dataset info in order to differenciate each button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is documented in [`Node.appendChild()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

> If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document,
>   appendChild() moves it from its current position to the new position
>   (there is no requirement to remove the node from its parent node
>   before appending it to some other node).

Instead, instantiate a new button for each `li` within your loop:

```js
function createButtonElement() {
  var a = document.querySelectorAll("li");

  for (var v = 0; v < a.length; v++) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");

    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete Me"));
    a[v].appendChild(btn);
  }
}
```

```html
<li>a</li>
<li>b</li>
<li>c</li>
<button onclick="createButtonElement()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You created only one button  and append it on the first `<LI>`, then you append it to the second `<LI>`... as he can't be on two different place this command move your button to the second place, and so on.

to duplicate élent you have to use the **cloneNode** method : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

sample code :

```js
const MyList     = document.querySelector('#My-List')
  ,   AddButtons = document.querySelector('#Add-Buttons')

AddButtons.onclick=_=>
{
  let newBt = document.createElement('button')
  newBt.textContent = 'Delete Me'
  document.querySelectorAll("#My-List li").forEach(eLI=>eLI.appendChild( newBt.cloneNode(true)) )
}

MyList.onclick=e=>
{
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() !='button') return
  let pLI = e.target.parentElement
  MyList.removeChild(pLI)
}
```

```html
<button id="Add-Buttons">Add Buttons to each element on list</button>

<ul id="My-List">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

**PLUS**
I added the way to deal with the click on the added buttons, via the event delegation

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new button for each item, otherwise the button just moves from item to item until you get to the last one.

```js
function createButtonElement() {
   var a = document.querySelectorAll("li");

   for(var v =0; v<a.length;v++)
   {
      let btn = document.createElement("button");   
      btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete Me"));
      a[v].appendChild(btn);
   }   
}
```

```html
<button onclick="createButtonElement()">click</button>

<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the button for each li element

```
function createButtonElement() {
  var a = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  for(var v =0; v<a.length;v++) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Delete Me"));
    a[v].appendChild(btn);
  }   
}
```